# d3 how to transitions image together with slice in pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a project where I draw a doughnut/pie chart. Each slice in the chart consists of a group which in term has a path(the slice) and an image.

In order to transition the slices I have used the general update pattern to update the slices and added two attrTween methods to handle the transitions of the slices.

In order to add the images to the slices I have first put each slice into a group. Then I add an image to each group and use the `arc.centroid` method in order to position the images in the center of each slice. This works very well the first time I load the in the chart. But when the chart updates, the images stay in the center of their group as it was positioned previously.

I have console logged both the `d` element and the output of the `arc.controid` method with that `d` element. You can see clearly that the coordinates of the `d` elements don't change and that is why the images don't get an updated new position. But I do not get why they still get the old version of this d element and not the new updated one.

```
.append("svg:image")
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
      if (i === 1) {
        console.log(d);
        console.log(this.arc.centroid(d));
      }
      var x = this.arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
      var y = this.arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
      return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    })
```

This is a snippet of the code I am using. I have tried to keep this as short as possible. But all the elements that are included are needed in order to get this snippet to work for this particular problem:

```js
var margin = 1;

this.width = 250;
this.height = 250;

this.index = 0;

this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2 - margin;

this.svg = d3
  .select(".canvas")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", this.width)
  .attr("height", this.height)
  .append("g")
  .attr(
    "transform",
    "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + this.height / 2 + ")"
  );

this.pie = d3
  .pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(d => d.value);

this.arc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(100)
  .innerRadius(50);


const setSlicesOnDoughnut = (data) => {
  this.arcs = this.svg.selectAll("path").data(this.pie(data[this.index]));

  this.arcs.join(
    enter => {
      enter
        .append("g")
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .each(function(d) {
          this._current = d;
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", arcTweenEnter);
    },

    update => {
      update
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", arcTweenUpdate);
    },

    exit => {
      exit.remove();
    }
  );
}

const addImagesToSlices = () => {
  var image_width = 20;
  var image_height = 20;

  this.svg.selectAll("image").remove();

  this.svg
    .selectAll("g")
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
      if (i === 1) {
        console.log(d);
        console.log(this.arc.centroid(d));
      }
      var x = this.arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
      var y = this.arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
      return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    })
    .attr("class", "logo")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return `${d.data.key}-logo`;
    })
    .attr("href", d => d.data.icon)
    .attr("width", image_width)
    .attr("height", image_height)
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr("opacity", 1);
}

var data = [
  [{
      key: "One",
      value: 20,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Two",
      value: 30,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Three",
      value: 10,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Four",
      value: 15,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    }
  ],
  [{
      key: "One",
      value: 30,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Two",
      value: 15,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Three",
      value: 20,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Four",
      value: 10,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    }
  ]
]

const arcTweenEnter = (d) => {
  var i = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, d.startAngle);

  return t => {
    d.startAngle = i(t);
    return this.arc(d);
  };
}

const arcTweenUpdate = (d, i, n) => {
  var interpolate = d3.interpolate(n[i]._current, d);
  n[i]._current = d;
  return t => {
    return this.arc(interpolate(t));
  };
}

setSlicesOnDoughnut(data);
addImagesToSlices();

const swap = document.querySelector(".swap");
swap.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (this.index === 0) this.index = 1;
  else this.index = 0;
  setSlicesOnDoughnut(data);
  addImagesToSlices();
});
```

```html
<button class="swap">swap</button>
<div class="canvas"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you never update the datum bound to the `g`. Let's look at how you enter and update the wedges:

```
this.arcs = this.svg.selectAll("path").data(this.pie(data[this.index]));

this.arcs.join(

  enter => {
    enter
      .append("g")
      .append("path")
      ...

  },

  update => {
    update
      .transition()
      ...
  },
```

You select all the *paths* and bind data to them (`selectAll("path")`). On enter you append a `g`, which means the `g` gets a bound datum, as does the child `path`. On update however, as you've only selected paths, you only bind new data to the paths. The parent `g` is left with the original bound datum.

Instead, let's select the parent `g` with selectAll, and tweak our update function slightly to account for this:

```
// select parent g elements instead of paths:
this.arcs = this.svg.selectAll("g").data(this.pie(data[this.index]));

this.arcs.join(

  enter => {
    enter
      .append("g")
      .append("path")
      ...

  },

  update => {
    update
      .select("path") // select the child  path.
      .transition()
      ...
  },
```

Now when we (re-)append the images, they are using the most recent datum bound to their parent `g`:

```js
var margin = 1;

this.width = 250;
this.height = 250;

this.index = 0;

this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2 - margin;

this.svg = d3
  .select(".canvas")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", this.width)
  .attr("height", this.height)
  .append("g")
  .attr(
    "transform",
    "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + this.height / 2 + ")"
  );

this.pie = d3
  .pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(d => d.value);

this.arc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(100)
  .innerRadius(50);


const setSlicesOnDoughnut = (data) => {
  this.arcs = this.svg.selectAll("g").data(this.pie(data[this.index]));

  this.arcs.join(
    enter => {
      enter
        .append("g")
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .each(function(d) {
          this._current = d;
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", arcTweenEnter);
    },

    update => {
      update
        .select("path")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", arcTweenUpdate);
    },

    exit => {
      exit.remove();
    }
  );
}

const addImagesToSlices = () => {
  var image_width = 20;
  var image_height = 20;

  this.svg.selectAll("image").remove();

  this.svg
    .selectAll("g")
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
      if (i === 1) {
        console.log(this.arc.centroid(d));
      }
      var x = this.arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
      var y = this.arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
      return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    })
    .attr("class", "logo")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return `${d.data.key}-logo`;
    })
    .attr("href", d => d.data.icon)
    .attr("width", image_width)
    .attr("height", image_height)
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr("opacity", 1);
}

var data = [
  [{
      key: "One",
      value: 20,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Two",
      value: 30,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Three",
      value: 10,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Four",
      value: 15,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    }
  ],
  [{
      key: "One",
      value: 30,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Two",
      value: 15,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Three",
      value: 20,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    },
    {
      key: "Four",
      value: 100,
      icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
    }
  ]
]

const arcTweenEnter = (d) => {
  var i = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, d.startAngle);

  return t => {
    d.startAngle = i(t);
    return this.arc(d);
  };
}

const arcTweenUpdate = (d, i, n) => {
  var interpolate = d3.interpolate(n[i]._current, d);
  n[i]._current = d;
  return t => {
    return this.arc(interpolate(t));
  };
}

setSlicesOnDoughnut(data);
addImagesToSlices();

const swap = document.querySelector(".swap");
swap.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (this.index === 0) this.index = 1;
  else this.index = 0;
  setSlicesOnDoughnut(data);
  addImagesToSlices();
});
```

```html
<button class="swap">swap</button>
<div class="canvas"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
```